# How would I implement Next/Previous Buttons to cycle through tabular data in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm creating a nutritional data table, and I want to cycle through displaying calories, protein, total fat etc. by pressing the next button or previous to change what value the table displays.
My current table is: http://jsfiddle.net/Zku6N/

```
        <table id='mealSection' border="1" rules="rows">
       <caption id="mealCaption"><b>Your Meal</b></caption>
       <!--nested table-->
       <tr><td align="center"><table>
          <tr><td><input type="button" id="prevValue" value="<"/></td><td style="width:100px" align="center"><b>Calories</b></td><td><input type="button" id="nextValue" value=">"/></td></tr>
        </table></td><tr>
        <!--nested table-->
        <tr><td><table id='info' border="1" rules="rows">
      <tr><td><b>Item Name:</b></td><td><b>Value:</b></td></tr>
        <tr><td id="itemName" style="width:160px"></td><td id="itemInfo" style="width:60px"></td></tr>
      </table></td></tr>
      </table>
```

The table is hardcoded to display calories. How can I cycle through calories, protein, and total fat with the next button, and changing the value of "id=itemInfo" at the same time?

Answer (score 2):

I would put the whole lot in one table, hiding the appropriate columns with CSS. Something along the lines of:

```
<table id="mealPlanner">
    <caption id="mealCaption"><b>Your Meal</b>

    </caption>

    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2" class="calories">
                <input type="button" class="prev" value="<" />Calories
                <input type="button" class="next" value=">" />
            </th>
            <th colspan="2" class="protien">
                <input type="button" class="prev" value="<" />Protien
                <input type="button" class="next" value=">" />
            </th>
            <th colspan="2" class="fat">
                <input type="button" class="prev" value="<" />Total Fat
                <input type="button" class="next" value=">" />
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th class="calories">Item Name</th>
            <th class="calories">Item Value</th>
            <th class="protien">Item Name</th>
            <th class="protien">Item Value</th>
            <th class="fat">Item Name</th>
            <th class="fat">Item Value</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="calories">Name</td>
            <td class="calories">Value</td>
            <td class="protien">Name</td>
            <td class="protien">Value</td>
            <td class="fat">Name</td>
            <td class="fat">Value</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

With the following CSS:

```
.protien, .fat {

    display:none;

}
```

Then wire up the following javascript/jquery:

```
/*Calories*/
$("th.calories .next").click(function () {
    $(".calories").hide();
    $(".protien").show();
});


$("th.calories .prev").click(function () {
    $(".calories").hide();
    $(".fat").show();
});

/*Protein*/
$("th.protien .next").click(function () {
    $(".protien").hide();
    $(".fat").show();
});


$("th.protien .prev").click(function () {
    $(".protien").hide();
    $(".calories").show();
});

/*Fat*/
$("th.fat .next").click(function () {
    $(".fat").hide();
    $(".calories").show();
});


$("th.fat .prev").click(function () {
    $(".fat").hide();
    $(".protien").show();
});
```

There would be more elegant ways of doing this with fewer lines and being more DRY but this is fairly simple and self explanatory and you should be aable to adapt it should you wish to use nested tables.

See it action here: http://jsfiddle.net/6ZPmm/1/